# Connection Leibniz rule

Tags: riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

This is my definition for a connection on a vector bundle.

> Let $E \to M$ be a vector bundle. A **connection** on $E \to M$ is a bilinear map $$\nabla : \mathfrak{X}(M) \times \Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(E), \ \ (X, s) \mapsto \nabla_Xs,$$ that is $C^\infty(M)$-linear in the first entry an fulfils the Leibniz rule $$\nabla_X(fs)=X(f)s + f\nabla_X s.$$

In the notes I'm reading it is being said that the condition on the Leibniz rule can be written as $$\nabla(fs)=s \otimes df + f\nabla s$$

if we drop the vector field $X$.

I'm not understanding this quite. Where is the tensor product coming from and what does it mean to "drop" $X$ from this? This would then be a map $\nabla :\Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(E)$.

Comment: I have rewritten my answer below to be more precise. I hope this will help remove some of the confusion I may have caused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second definition views a connection as a map $\nabla : \Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(T^*M\otimes E)$, so given $s \in \Gamma(E)$, we have $\nabla s \in \Gamma(T^*M\otimes E)$. Using the isomorphism $T^*M\otimes E \cong \operatorname{Hom}(TM, E)$, the element $\nabla s \in \Gamma(M, T^*M\otimes E)$ corresponds to an element $\overline{\nabla s} \in \Gamma(M, \operatorname{Hom}(TM, E))$. If $X \in \mathfrak{X}(M) = \Gamma(TM)$, then $(\overline{\nabla s})(X) \in \Gamma(E)$; this is precisely $\nabla_Xs$ according to the first definition, i.e. $(\overline{\nabla s})(X) = \nabla_Xs$.

With this in mind, the Leibniz rule for the two definitions correspond in the same way. Note that

$$(\overline{\nabla(fs)})(X) = \nabla_X(fs) = X(f)s + f\nabla_Xs= df(X)s + f(\overline{\nabla s})(X).$$

Recall that for finite-dimensional vector spaces $V$ and $W$, the isomorphism $V^*\otimes W \to \operatorname{Hom}(V, W)$ is generated by $\alpha\otimes w \mapsto L$ where $L(v) = \alpha(v)w$. So under the isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}(TM, E) \cong T^*M\otimes E$, the map $X \mapsto df(X)s$ corresponds to $df\otimes s$, i.e. $df(X)s = (\overline{df\otimes s})(X) = df(X)s$. Therefore

$$(\overline{\nabla(fs)})(X) = df(X) s + f(\overline{\nabla s})(X) = (\overline{df\otimes s})(X) + f(\overline{\nabla s})(X) = (\overline{df\otimes s + f\nabla s})(X),$$

so $\overline{\nabla(fs)} = \overline{df\otimes s + f\nabla s}$, and hence $\nabla(fs) = df\otimes s + f\nabla s$.

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly the connection can be defined as a map $\nabla : \Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(E\otimes T^*M)$, but $E\otimes T^*M \cong \operatorname{Hom}(TM, E)$ so a connection would be a map $\nabla : \Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(\operatorname{Hom}(TM, E))$? I am not sure how to interpret $\Gamma(\operatorname{Hom}(TM, E))$. @michael-albanese

Comment: You are understanding it correctly. The map $\nabla : \Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(\operatorname{Hom}(TM, E))$ is $s \mapsto \nabla s$. Note that $(\nabla s)(fX) = f(\nabla s)(X)$ so $\nabla s$ is $C^{\infty}(M)$-linear, and therefore $\nabla s : \Gamma(TM) \to \Gamma(E)$ corresponds to an element of $\Gamma(\operatorname{Hom}(TM, E))$, see Lemma $10.29$ of Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (second edition).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. If I may ask why are these two definitions for a connection equivalent? At least for now it is not obvious to me. @michael-albanese

Comment: Because the equation $(\nabla s)(X) = \nabla_Xs$ shows you how to go from a connection according to one definition to a connection according to the other.

Comment: So $\nabla : \Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(E\otimes T^*M)$ will give me a $\nabla s$ which is  an $E$-valued $1$-form since $\Gamma(E\otimes T^*M) = \Omega^1(T^*M, E)$ and if I pick a vector field $X \in \Gamma(TM)$ first I have $\nabla_X : \Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(E)$ which gives me a map $$\nabla_X s : M \to E$$ i.e. a section of $E$? I suspect that $\nabla_X s$ is defined on points of $M$ by $$\nabla_X s(p) = \nabla_{X_p} s?$$ @michael-albanese

Comment: This is correct. A priori, the value of the section $\nabla_Xs$ at $p$ depends on $X$, not just $X_p$, but it turns out that it does only depend on $X_p$, see Lemma $4.2$ of Lee's *Riemannian Manifolds: An Introduction to Curvature* and the discussion which follows.